# How to prevent the cursor in tinymce editor?

Tags: tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor,

http://beyondthelogix.com/demos/editordemo/demo.html

When I click on the equation symbol in the toolbar,an editable span is automatically created with a class 'AMedit' in the editor.

Now my question is: if the cursor is just after the ending single quote of this span,that `<span class="AMedit">'some text'</span>`,

The backspace key should not work. More simple, once the cursor is outside this span, the backspace key should not move it back to the span.

This will not be a single span,this span is created everytime we click the equation symbol in the toolbar.

You can check it live. I have noted the link above.

So if you guys have some idea about this, Please help me in this.

Thanks to All!

Comment: "More simple, once the cursor is outside this span, the backspace key should not move it back to the span." -why not?

Comment: I need this for some purpose,that is why i need backspace not to move the cursor back to the span.

Comment: the only way to handle this will be to catch the backspace event, check if this special case occurs and then stop the propagation